# How do I get a list of react.js routes from a database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, react-router

So I have node.js + react and react-router and I want to generate the routes from a list taken from a database. How can I make something like this

```
<Route component={App}>
  <Route name="Home" path="/" component={Page}/>
  <Route name="Page1" path="/page1" component={Page}/>
  <Route name="Page2" path="/page2" component={Page}/>
  ...
</Route>
```

and use it in my application?
My current files look like this:

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
var routes = require('./app/routes');
...
app.use(function(req, res) {
  Router.match({ routes: routes.default, location: req.url }, function(err, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
        var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(Router.RoutingContext, renderProps));
        //var page = swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: html });
        res.status(200).send('<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ro"><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="./foundation-6/css/foundation.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css"></head><body><div id="app"></div><script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script></script><script src="./js/vendor.js"></script><script src="./js/vendor.bundle.js"></script><script src="./js/bundle.js"></script><script src="./foundation-6/js/foundation.min.js"></script><script>$(document).foundation();var socket = io();</script></body></html>');
    } else {
      res.status(404).send('Page Not Found')
    }
  });
});
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Page from './components/Page';

export default (
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route name="Home" path="/" component={Page}/>
    <Route name="Test" path="/test" component={Page}/>
  </Route>
);
```

**Edit**

I just want to get a list of pages. All of the pages will use the same component, but they will have different title and content. I can query the database, but I don't know hot to pass the object to the reactjs and generate routes based on it.

Comment: First question: why are you trying to store this into a database? Are you trying to store just the routes in there (why?) or are you also trying to store components in there as well?

Also, what are you having trouble with? Querying the database? Iterating over a recordset? Maybe try breaking down the tasks to do this into smaller pieces and trying to solve them individually.

Comment: No. I just want to get a list of pages. As I said in the example, all of them will use the same component, but they will have different title and content. I can query the database, but I don't know hot to pass the object to the reactjs and generate routes based on it.

Comment: You can try using plain objects, as mentioned at the bottom of the page. Then the problem amounts to converting the database output into a plain js object:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#user-content-configuration-with-plain-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get the data you need as an array within your code, you could do something like this:

```
// assuming data is like [{path:'/', name:'Home'}, {path: '/page1', name: 'Page 1'}, ...] 

<Route component={App}>
  {data.map((obj, i) => { <Route name={obj.name} path={obj.path} component={Page}/> }
</Route>
```

Answer (score -1):

Turns out react-router already has object schema, so as log as you store your routes in the db in that structure, you can use it:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md#configuration-with-plain-routes

Comment: (this source out of date)